# Is it true that you can't take money out of the market using only risk management?

Tags: stocks, day-trading, risk-management

Is it really true what a lot of traders say: that in order for you to make money in the stock market it suffices to use risk management?

For the following reasons, I think it is not true:

Suppose you have a 1:2 risk reward ratio meaning that for every 1 dollar you are risking to lose you may win 2.

Suppose the stock price is 10 and you either lose 2 or win 4 in accordance with the aforementioned risk reward ratio.

The fundamental issue here is that you have more chance of losing 2 than winning 4. In the long run you will have no profit.

You can better understand this with the following reasoning:

There is 50% chance that the price will rise to 14 and 50% chance that the price will fall to 6, this anyone would agree. If it were possible to see all the possible price paths that would lead the price from 10 to 14 you would see a lot situations where the price would firstly fall back to 7 and then rise to 14. When you put an assymetric risk reward ratio like 1:2 you're cutting off those price moves which would lead to 14 so your chance is really smaller of getting to 14.

Thus, it does not seem to me that you can simply can't take money out of the market in the long run using risk reward management.

You can repeat the risk management procedure some times and it seems to work, but in the long run you will give all the money back. That is what statistics tells us.

Is my analysis correct, or have I missed something?

Comment: You offer a contrived example of risk management which you then dispute. The question can still use some clarification. Your conclusion of long term breaking even (giving the money back) makes no sense.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica that's called a straw man, no?

Comment: How do you get to the 50% chance of 14 and 50% chance of 6, in that case I would argue that that risk reward is **not ** 1:2 but rather 1:1, you either lose 4 or win 4. Also you say that you have more chance of losing than winning - that kind of contradicts your whole premise with the *50% chance *, which indicates that chances are equal.

Comment: @RonJohn - yes. That’s the technical logical fallacy here. I’m still struggling to understand OP’s actual question. One we can answer

Comment: @ssn The 50% chance is obtained as follows: You have only two possibilites, one of which will occur, what is the chance that one of them occur (disregarding any kind of bias)? It like flipping a coin, you have two possible outcome, if the coin is fair the probability of getting a head is 50% and of getting a tail is 50%. There is no issue here.

Comment: @ssn I didn't say you have more chance of losing than winning in the case 1:1, I said you have more chance of losing in the case 1:2, so there is not any contradiction in the argument.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica you can't say if makes no sense if you don't tell me your winning ratio. For instance, if you win only 30% of the time, even winning twice as much you will end up losing money. The conjecture is that your winning ratio will in fact be lower.

Comment: @PtF please explain like I am fine then; in which game would you ever expect a 2 dollar reward for every one dollar at risk where the odds are 50-50? Expected reward is then 0.5x2 + 0.5x-1 = 0.5 (>0). Odds are always in your favor.

Comment: I don't expect that because such a game does not exist in any reasonable scenario.

Comment: @PtF - your example premise, a 50% chance of 14 50% chance of 6 for a $10 stock  is a setup for a hypothetical argument. You don't mention a timeframe, for example, but worse, you ignore all other outcomes. Why would a $10 stock have zero chance for the full range between 6-14?  The question can use quite a bit more editing, although you seem to be happy with one posted answer. Maybe nanoman understands something I am missing.

Comment: It seems a logical set up which captures a scenario where a stock randomly starts from a price and will go up or will fall down, can you explain the problem with that? It does not have zero chance, how did you get to that conclusion? The accepted answer is based upon convincing mathematical arguments from my point of view, that is why it was accepted.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica the experminent ends when the price gets to 6 or to 14. Of course that at certain times the value will be between 6 and 14 but the point is that in the long run it is reasonable to expect it will reach either 6 or 14.

Comment: The point is, you have to wait for the experiment to end.

Comment: Perhaps my English comprehension is failing a bit. I appreciate the clarification. I missed where you said in the setup that one buys a $10 stock and ends the experiment at $14 or $6 which ever comes first. I get that now. I 100% disagree that these events each have a 50% chance of occurring. "this anyone would agree" Hardly.  The chance of a stock gaining 40% is far higher than losing 40%. Not all binary choices are 50/50.  I will live to see 2021 or I'll die by year end. I hope that's not 50/50. Thus, my pushback on the setup of this question.

Comment: I agree the odds are that a company should likely appreciate, but that is something I can't quantify without adding too much complexity to the problem, that is the reason why the assumption 50/50, I thought that would be the most unbiased scenario. But In fact, when computing some statistics from past data it seems to be the case there is a higher return bias. This would in fact destroy my argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect what you mean by "take money out of the market" is obtaining returns above the market average, i.e., "beating the market". Indeed, your intuition is correct that unless you can statistically predict stock returns better than the "random walk" model, you cannot beat the market just by applying "risk management rules" like profit targets or stop losses.

The deep reason for this is the [optional stopping theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem), which says that there is no winning strategy for betting on fair coin flips -- or more generally, on similar processes known as martingales. The random walk model describes the deviations of stock returns from the average return as martingales, so the implication is that there isn't any successful "market timing" strategy for benefiting from these deviations.

Answer (score 1):

> There is 50% chance that the price will rise to 14 and 50% chance that the price will fall to 6, this anyone would agree.

No, absolutely not. The chance of the price going to 14 is significantly greater than the chance of the price going to 6.

> Is my analysis correct, or have I missed something?

What you've missed is the fact that on average, stocks are profitable.

The reason for this is that on average, *business* is profitable. If I buy an apple orchard, then the value of the apples it produces will probably be greater than the cost of the labor, machinery and supplies needed to grow the apples. The same goes for all kinds of business: on average, business activities produce more value than they consume.

It's a gamble, but it's a gamble where the investor has the edge. In the long run (say, over the course of 40 years), the risks are pretty small relative to the rewards.

Comment: The conclusions anyone can make are based upon premisses. If I take your premisse as true I agree with your conclusions. It is an interesting point of view.

Comment: The Nikkei 225 index is still about 40% below it's 1989 peak, 30 years ago.  Have Japanese businesses been unprofitable?

Comment: @user662852 IIRC, the Nikkei 225 was in a **giant** bubble.  Has the N225 *generally* trended upwards since then, and how much would dividend reinvestment have helped the unlucky sod who bought at the peak and held until now?

Answer (score 1):

You need an edge to make money over long term.

Proper risk management will increase your sharpe ratio and protect against bankruptcy.   Even with a strong edge you can go bankrupt without proper risk management.

Ways of risk management is diversification, stops and not having too high leverage.

Answer (score 1):

The one armed bandits in Vegas are programmed somewhere near a 40% payout.  During a short period of play, you may win, you may lose because it's a finite sample.  Over the long haul, the house wins.

It's the same with your hypothetical set up. If the odds are even that "you have a 1:2 risk reward ratio meaning that for every 1 dollar you are risking to lose you may win 2" then you will make money.  There's a positive expected return.

However, your  contrived set up has nothing to do with risk management.  You have  described the risk of the bet not its management.

Risk management means just that.  You do something actively to reduce risk.  It could be using stop orders (and hoping that there are no gaps).

In the world of options, a risk management  example would be rolling long calls up as they become profitable, booking gains and reducing cost basis (risk management).  Or selling OTM calls against those long calls.  Or buying some puts after the run up to lock in gains.  All of these actions lowered the risk.